# "Every" and "Any" not returning value in Maria DB

Tags: sql, mariadb

`Every` and `Any` are 2 type of aggregate functions in Maria DB. These functions [return true or false based on boolean values](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/sql-99/set-functions/) in them.

While using MariaDB installed in xampp with following **server version**, i cannot get these functions tested in my local environment using queries :

```
select any(column_name) from table_name
```

**Server Version** :

```
Server type: MariaDB
Server version: 10.1.21-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
```

Any idea to sort issues ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are pointing at in the knowledge base is not MariaDB syntax, it's SQL-99 standard. In [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/subqueries-and-any) (and [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/any-in-some-subqueries.html)) *implementations*, `ANY`, `SOME` and `ALL` are not aggregate functions. They aren't exactly functions or operators at all, they are referred to as just "words", used between a comparison operator and a subquery, e.g.

```
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE t1 (f1 INT);
MariaDB [test]> CREATE TABLE t2 (f2 INT);
MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO t1 VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);
MariaDB [test]> INSERT INTO t2 VALUES (1),(2);

MariaDB [test]> SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE f1 > ANY( SELECT f2 FROM t2 );
+------+
| f1   |
+------+
|    2 |
|    3 |
|    4 |
+------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: ,yes it was about sql99, i thought it had something to do with MariaDb syntax..thank you for writing a good post